# How to set data from different lists in listview using baseadapter

Tags: java, android, listview, baseadapter

I have an `arraylist` and I need to show data from 3 different arraylists:

- BookingsModel
- CompositionDataSet
- Dataset

Each list contains some data and I have to set data from these lists to my list view. I am using `baseadapter`. How can I achieve this?
Please help me. I tried many ways but nothing works. 
I am completely blank now.

Pages.java:

```
    private List<BookingsModel> completiondate = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<CompositionDataSet> pageno = new ArrayList<>();
 private List<Dataset> Name = new ArrayList<>();

        private ListView listView;
        private PagesAdapter pageadapter;
        private String androidOS;
        private String device_uuid;
        private String contributor_id;
        public String tocName;
        public String categoryName;
        private SessionManager session;
        private String first_Page;
        private String last_Page;
        private String current_Page;
        private String firstPage;
        private String lastPage;
        private String currentPage;
        ProgressDialog loading;
        private String page;
        private String page_no;
        private String name;
        private String lastDate;
        private String category_image;
        private String category_name;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
            getSupportActionBar().show();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_pages);
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            page = getIntent().getExtras().getString("CONTENT");
            page_no = getIntent().getExtras().getString("PAGENO");
            name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("NAME");
    //        lastDate = getIntent().getExtras().getString("COMPLETION");
    //        category_image = getIntent().getExtras().getString("CATEGORY_IMAGE");
            session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
            SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences("preferences", 0);
            firstPage = pref.getString("firstpage",null);
            lastPage = pref.getString("lastpage",null);
            currentPage = pref.getString("currentpage",null);
            contributor_id = pref.getString("contributor_id",null);

    //        loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Loading Data", "Please wait...",false,false);
            //getData();

    //        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            androidOS = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
            device_uuid = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
           pageadapter = new PagesAdapter(this,completiondate,pageno,names);
                    listView.setAdapter(pageadapter);

        }
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Pages.this, RecordComposition.class);
        i.putExtra("PAGE",page);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

PageAdapter.java:

```
    public class PagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final Object TAG = null;
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<BookingsModel> completiondate;
    private List<CompositionDataSet> pageno;
    private List<DataSet> names;
    int pagenumber;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    public PagesAdapter(Activity activity, List<BookingsModel> date, List<CompositionDataSet> page,List<DataSet> name) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.completiondate = date;
        this.pageno = page;
        this.names = name;
        //this.pagenumber=pageIndex;
    }




    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return DataList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return DataList.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


//        if(pagenumber==0){

            if (inflater == null)
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null)
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pages_view, null);

            if (imageLoader == null)
                imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
            NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lastdate);
            TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView page = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.page_no);
            BookingsModel m = completiondate.get(position);
            CompositionDataSet n = pageno.get(position);
            DataSet o = names.get(position);
            date.setText(m.getCompletion());
            page.setText(n.getPageno());
            name.setText(names.get(position).getName());
            Log.d((String) TAG,"Reponse  :"+m.getCompletion());
             Log.d((String) TAG,"Reponse Check :"+n.getPageno());
        Log.d((String) TAG,"Reponse Check :"+o.getName());

        return convertView;

    }
```

These are the list data in logcat:

```
 [ 05-22 18:01:59.047 25996:25996 D/         ]
                                                                               Reponse Check :[BookingModel{TableOfContent=DataSet{id='1', name='গোরা', category_id='1', language_id='1', created='2016-03-09 03:39:01', modified='2016-03-09 14:39:01', BookingsCategory=BookingsCategory{id='1', name='Novels', description='A work of Rabindranath tagore', image='novels.png', parent_id='0', language_id='1', created='2016-03-09 00:24:59', modified='2016-03-09 11:53:21'}}}, BookingModel{TableOfContent=DataSet{id='3062', name='A BEAST'S BONY frame (73: Poems)', category_id='2', language_id='2', created='2016-04-18 15:29:47', modified='2016-04-18 15:29:47', BookingsCategory=BookingsCategory{id='2', name='Verses', description='The complete verses works of Rabindranath Tagore', image='verses.png', parent_id='0', language_id='1', created='2016-03-09 00:30:12', modified='2016-03-09 11:30:12'}}}, BookingModel{TableOfContent=DataSet{id='6781', name='চার অধ্যায়', category_id='1', language_id='1', created='2016-04-20 11:01:07', modified='2016-04-20 11:01:07', BookingsCategory=BookingsCategory{id='1', name='Novels', description='A work of Rabindranath tagore', image='novels.png', parent_id='0', language_id='1', created='2016-03-09 00:24:59', modified='2016-03-09 11:53:21'}}}, BookingModel{TableOfContent=DataSet{id='3066', name='A MESSAGE CAME from my youth (40: Lover's Gift)', category_id='2', language_id='2', created='2016-04-18 15:29:47', modified='2016-04-18 15:29:47', BookingsCategory=BookingsCategory{id='2', name='Verses', description='The complete verses works of Rabindranath Tagore', image='verses.png', parent_id='0', language_id='1', created='2016-03-09 00:30:12', modified='2016-03-09 11:30:12'}}}, BookingModel{TableOfContent=DataSet{id='3064', name='A HANDFUL OF dust could hide your signal when I did not know its meaning. (5: Fruit-Gathering)', category_id='2', language_id='2', created='2016-04-18 15:29:47', modified='2016-04-18 15:29:47', BookingsCategory=BookingsCategory{id='2', name='Verses', description='The complete verses works of Rabindranath Tagore', image='verses.png', parent_id='0', language_id='1', created='2016-03-09 00:30:12', modified='2016-03-09 11:30:12'}}}, BookingModel{TableOfContent=DataSet{id='6789', name='যোগাযোগ', category_id='1', language_id='1', created='2016-04-20 11:29:19', modified='2016-04-20 11:29:19', BookingsCategory=BookingsCategory{id='1', name='Novels', description='A work of Rabindranath tagore', image='novels.png', parent_id='0', language_id='1', created='2016-03-09 00:24:59', modified='2016-03-09 11:53:21'}}}]

                                                                               [ 05-22 18:01:59.047 25996:25996 D/         ]
                                                                               Reponse Check :[com.showhow2.www.thetagoreproject.Booking@cf65e47, com.showhow2.www.thetagoreproject.Booking@789f674, com.showhow2.www.thetagoreproject.Booking@8d779d, com.showhow2.www.thetagoreproject.Booking@71bf412, com.showhow2.www.thetagoreproject.Booking@33097e3, com.showhow2.www.thetagoreproject.Booking@68a05e0]

                                                                               [ 05-22 18:01:59.051 25996:25996 D/         ]
                                                                               Reponse Check :[CompositionModel{Composition=CompositionModel{id='11', content='সেদিন তর্কে গোরাকে অপদস্থ করিয়া সুচরিতার সম্মুখে নিজের জয়পতাকা তুলিয়া ধরিবার জন্য হারানের বিশেষ ইচ্ছা ছিল, গোড়ায় সুচরিতাও তাহার আশা করিয়াছিল। কিন্তু দৈবক্রমে ঠিক তার বিপরীত ঘটিল। ধর্মবিশ্বাস ও সামাজিক মতে সুচরিতার সঙ্গে গোরার মিল ছিল না। কিন্তু স্বদেশের প্রতি মমত্ব, স্বজাতির জন্য বেদনা তাহার পক্ষে স্বাভাবিক ছিল। যদিচ দেশের ব্যাপার লইয়া সে সর্বদা আলোচনা করে নাই, কিন্তু সেদিন স্বজাতির নিন্দায় গোরা যখন অকস্মাৎ বজ্রনাদ করিয়া উঠিল তখন সুচরিতার সমস্ত মনের মধ্যে তাহার অনুকূল প্রতিধ্বনি বাজিয়া উঠিয়াছিল। এমন বলের সঙ্গে এমন দৃঢ় বিশ্বাসের সঙ্গে দেশের সম্বন্ধে কেহ তাহার সম্মুখে কথা বলে নাই। সাধারণত আমাদের দেশের লোকেরা স্বজাতি ও স্বদেশের আলোচনায় কিছু-না-কিছু মুরুব্বিয়ানা ফলাইয়া থাকে; তাহাকে গভীর ভাবে সত্য ভাবে বিশ্বাস করে না; এইজন্য মুখে কবিত্ব করিবার বেলায় দেশের সম্বন্ধে যাহাই বলুক দেশের প্রতি তাহাদের ভরসা নাই; কিন্তু গোরা তাহার স্বদেশের সমস্ত দুঃখ-দুর্গতি দুর্বলতা ভেদ করিয়াও একটা মহৎ সত্যাপদার্থকে প্রত্যক্ষবৎ দেখিতে পাইত-- সেইজন্য দেশের দারিদ্র৻কে কিছুমাত্র অস্বীকার না করিয়াও সে দেশের প্রতি এমন একটি বলিষ্ঠ শ্রদ্ধা স্থাপন করিয়াছিল। দেশের অন্তর্নিহিত শক্তির প্রতি এমন তাহার অবিচলিত বিশ্বাস ছিল যে, তাহার কাছে আসিলে, তাহার দ্বিধাবিহীন দেশভক্তির বাণী শুনিলে সংশয়ীকে হার মানিতে হইত। গোরার এই অক্ষুণ্ন ভক্তির সম্মুখে হারানের অবজ্ঞাপূর্ণ তর্ক সুচরিতাকে প্রতি মুহূর্তে যেন অপমানের মতো বাজিতেছিল। সে মাঝে মাঝে সংকোচ বিসর্জন দিয়া উচ্ছ্বসিত হৃদয়ে প্রতিবাদ না করিয়া থাকিতে পারে নাই।
                                                                                তাহার পরে হারান যখন গোরা ও বিনয়ের অসাক্ষাতে ক্ষুদ্র-ঈর্ষা-বশত তাহাদের প্রতি অভদ্রতার অপবাদ আরোপ করিলেন তখনো এই অন্�

                                                                               [ 05-22 18:01:59.052 25996:25996 D/         ]
                                                                               list Check2 :[DataSet{id='1', name='গোরা', category_id='1', language_id='1', created='2016-03-09 03:39:01', modified='2016-03-09 14:39:01', BookingsCategory=BookingsCategory{id='1', name='Novels', description='A work of Rabindranath tagore', image='novels.png', parent_id='0', language_id='1', created='2016-03-09 00:24:59', modified='2016-03-09 11:53:21'}}, DataSet{id='3062', name='A BEAST'S BONY frame (73: Poems)', category_id='2', language_id='2', created='2016-04-18 15:29:47', modified='2016-04-18 15:29:47', BookingsCategory=BookingsCategory{id='2', name='Verses', description='The complete verses works of Rabindranath Tagore', image='verses.png', parent_id='0', language_id='1', created='2016-03-09 00:30:12', modified='2016-03-09 11:30:12'}}, DataSet{id='6781', name='চার অধ্যায়', category_id='1', language_id='1', created='2016-04-20 11:01:07', modified='2016-04-20 11:01:07', BookingsCategory=BookingsCategory{id='1', name='Novels', description='A work of Rabindranath tagore', image='novels.png', parent_id='0', language_id='1', created='2016-03-09 00:24:59', modified='2016-03-09 11:53:21'}}, DataSet{id='3066', name='A MESSAGE CAME from my youth (40: Lover's Gift)', category_id='2', language_id='2', created='2016-04-18 15:29:47', modified='2016-04-18 15:29:47', BookingsCategory=BookingsCategory{id='2', name='Verses', description='The complete verses works of Rabindranath Tagore', image='verses.png', parent_id='0', language_id='1', created='2016-03-09 00:30:12', modified='2016-03-09 11:30:12'}}, DataSet{id='3064', name='A HANDFUL OF dust could hide your signal when I did not know its meaning. (5: Fruit-Gathering)', category_id='2', language_id='2', created='2016-04-18 15:29:47', modified='2016-04-18 15:29:47', BookingsCategory=BookingsCategory{id='2', name='Verses', description='The complete verses works of Rabindranath Tagore', image='verses.png', parent_id='0', language_id='1', created='2016-03-09 00:30:12', modified='2016-03-09 11:30:12'}}, DataSet{id='6789', name='যোগাযোগ', category_id='1', language_id='1', created='2016-04-20 11:29:19', modified='2016-04-20 11:29:19', BookingsCategory=BookingsCategory{id='1', name='Novels', description='A work of Rabindranath tagore', image='novels.png', parent_id='0', language_id='1', created='2016-03-09 00:24:59', modified='2016-03-09 11:53:21'}}]

                                                                               [ 05-22 18:01:59.057 25996:25996 D/         ]
                                                                               compositionlist Check2 :[CompositionModel{id='11', content='সেদিন তর্কে গোরাকে অপদস্থ করিয়া সুচরিতার সম্মুখে নিজের জয়পতাকা তুলিয়া ধরিবার জন্য হারানের বিশেষ ইচ্ছা ছিল, গোড়ায় সুচরিতাও তাহার আশা করিয়াছিল। কিন্তু দৈবক্রমে ঠিক তার বিপরীত ঘটিল। ধর্মবিশ্বাস ও সামাজিক মতে সুচরিতার সঙ্গে গোরার মিল ছিল না। কিন্তু স্বদেশের প্রতি মমত্ব, স্বজাতির জন্য বেদনা তাহার পক্ষে স্বাভাবিক ছিল। যদিচ দেশের ব্যাপার লইয়া সে সর্বদা আলোচনা করে নাই, কিন্তু সেদিন স্বজাতির নিন্দায় গোরা যখন অকস্মাৎ বজ্রনাদ করিয়া উঠিল তখন সুচরিতার সমস্ত মনের মধ্যে তাহার অনুকূল প্রতিধ্বনি বাজিয়া উঠিয়াছিল। এমন বলের সঙ্গে এমন দৃঢ় বিশ্বাসের সঙ্গে দেশের সম্বন্ধে কেহ তাহার সম্মুখে কথা বলে নাই। সাধারণত আমাদের দেশের লোকেরা স্বজাতি ও স্বদেশের আলোচনায় কিছু-না-কিছু মুরুব্বিয়ানা ফলাইয়া থাকে; তাহাকে গভীর ভাবে সত্য ভাবে বিশ্বাস করে না; এইজন্য মুখে কবিত্ব করিবার বেলায় দেশের সম্বন্ধে যাহাই বলুক দেশের প্রতি তাহাদের ভরসা নাই; কিন্তু গোরা তাহার স্বদেশের সমস্ত দুঃখ-দুর্গতি দুর্বলতা ভেদ করিয়াও একটা মহৎ সত্যাপদার্থকে প্রত্যক্ষবৎ দেখিতে পাইত-- সেইজন্য দেশের দারিদ্র৻কে কিছুমাত্র অস্বীকার না করিয়াও সে দেশের প্রতি এমন একটি বলিষ্ঠ শ্রদ্ধা স্থাপন করিয়াছিল। দেশের অন্তর্নিহিত শক্তির প্রতি এমন তাহার অবিচলিত বিশ্বাস ছিল যে, তাহার কাছে আসিলে, তাহার দ্বিধাবিহীন দেশভক্তির বাণী শুনিলে সংশয়ীকে হার মানিতে হইত। গোরার এই অক্ষুণ্ন ভক্তির সম্মুখে হারানের অবজ্ঞাপূর্ণ তর্ক সুচরিতাকে প্রতি মুহূর্তে যেন অপমানের মতো বাজিতেছিল। সে মাঝে মাঝে সংকোচ বিসর্জন দিয়া উচ্ছ্বসিত হৃদয়ে প্রতিবাদ না করিয়া থাকিতে পারে নাই।
                                                                                তাহার পরে হারান যখন গোরা ও বিনয়ের অসাক্ষাতে ক্ষুদ্র-ঈর্ষা-বশত তাহাদের প্রতি অভদ্রতার অপবাদ আরোপ করিলেন তখনো এই অন্যায় ক্ষু

                                                                               [ 05-22 18:01:59.057 25996:25996 D/         ]
                                                                               bookingsCategories Check2 :[BookingsCategory{id='1', name='Novels', description='A work of Rabindranath tagore', image='novels.png', parent_id='0', language_id='1', created='2016-03-09 00:24:59', modified='2016-03-09 11
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);



     int listNumber=0; //For Example its for list 1

    Context ctx;
    pageadapter = new PagesAdapter(this,completiondate,listNumber);

    }//End of Main Activity




        public class PagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private static final Object TAG = null;



     private List<BookingsModel> completiondate = new ArrayList<>(); //add list in your adapter 

        private Activity activity;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private List<BookingsModel> completiondate;
        private List<CompositionDataSet> pageno;
        private List<DataSet> names;
        int pagenumber;
        ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        public PagesAdapter(Activity activity, List<BookingsModel> date, List<CompositionDataSet> page,List<DataSet> name) {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.completiondate = date;
            this.pageno = page;
            this.names = name;
            //this.pagenumber=pageIndex;
        }




        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return completiondate .size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return completiondate .get(location);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


           if(pagenumber==0){ // Fro your First List that you are passing 

                if (inflater == null)
                    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                if (convertView == null)
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pages_view, null);

                if (imageLoader == null)
                    imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
                NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
                TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lastdate);
                TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                TextView page = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.page_no);
                BookingsModel m = completiondate.get(position);
                CompositionDataSet n = pageno.get(position);
                DataSet o = names.get(position);
                date.setText(m.getCompletion());
                page.setText(n.getPageno());
                name.setText(names.get(position).getName());
                Log.d((String) TAG,"Reponse  :"+m.getCompletion());
                 Log.d((String) TAG,"Reponse Check :"+n.getPageno());
            Log.d((String) TAG,"Reponse Check :"+o.getName());
    }
    else if(pagenumber==1) //code For your second list of that is passed 
{
 if (inflater == null)
                    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                if (convertView == null)
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pages_view, null);

                if (imageLoader == null)
                    imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
                NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
                TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lastdate);
                TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                TextView page = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.page_no);
                BookingsModel m = completiondate.get(position);
                CompositionDataSet n = pageno.get(position);
                DataSet o = names.get(position);
                date.setText(m.getCompletion());
                page.setText(n.getPageno());
                name.setText(names.get(position).getName());
                Log.d((String) TAG,"Reponse  :"+m.getCompletion());
                 Log.d((String) TAG,"Reponse Check :"+n.getPageno());
            Log.d((String) TAG,"Reponse Check :"+o.getName());
}

else if(==2)
{

//Code here for 3rd xml and list 

}

            return convertView;

        }
```

Comment: I have only one list view..in which i have to show data from 3 different arraylist

Comment: @Mobo why are you using ImageLoder ..?  usie Glide or Picasso..?

Comment: @Mobo is it working one you are using single list .?

Comment: No,that was also not working,But before that I created a String type array list and adding name to that arraylist in main activity and setting adapter.and in list view i was setting name using name.setText(names.get(position).getName());that time it was working.

Comment: @Mobo I think You Should Read some Basic Concepts About ArrayList and Object list.!

Comment: ok..I will go throug the concepts once more....but this is urgent...help me if you can.

Comment: i found the problem...why its not showing anything on screen...its because of  these lines  
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

Comment: I have updated code in my question...that is how it should be...but these three methods required for each list.how can i do that??

Comment: @Mobo thats mean you were passing Empty list to them.!

Comment: one thIng i am not getting is why are you using if(pagenumber==0){}else if(){} here....can u please explain?because there is only one xml file

Comment: @Mobo this is for your different Object List and your Different Xml Layout You can infilate them here.!

Comment: but unfortunately its not working..jst giving a blank listview

Comment: then you must be passing empty list

Comment: @Asif AbbAsi You can see the list data is not empty which i m passing...I have updated in my question.

Comment: @Asif AbbAsi you are right buddy...the list which i am passing is all empty...i got to knw after debuging app...can you please tell me why this is happening??

Comment: public PagesAdapter(Activity activity, List<BookingsModel> date, List<CompositionDataSet> page,List<DataSet> name) {
 super(activity,date,page,name);
        this.activity = activity;
        this.completiondate = date;
        this.pageno = page;
        this.names = name;
        //this.pagenumber=pageIndex;
    }
try this

Answer (score 0):

Can't you create a model with common attributes from all 3 models and create one list using that new model for the BaseAdapter?

Comment: it will be a great help if you can explain me how i can i do it or just by giving a sample of code.

Comment: nope it wont be good approach maybe for each model its view and data is different.? @Dulaj